# error C2679, std::ofstream, void how to fix?

Tags: c++, void

Here is my code. I don't know why I can't use `rez <<`. How can I fix this problem? Should I include something?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
void SS(int a, int b, int &SPP, int &SP) {
     SPP = a * b;
     SP = a * 2 + b * 2;
}
int main()
{
    ifstream fd("dviratininkas.txt");
    ofstream rez("rezultatas.txt");
    int n, a, b, SP, SPP;
    fd >> n;
    for (int i = 1; n > i; i++){
        fd >> a;
        fd >> b;
        rez << SS(a, b, SP, SPP) << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SS` returns `void`. What do you expect `rez << SS(...)` to do?

Comment: `SS(a, b, SP, SPP); rez << SP << " " << SPP << endl;`

Comment: im  expecting the value of  a, b SP ,SPP will be written in .txt file

Comment: @HeicPy If you want to write the values of a, b, SP, SPP to the text file, then you have to write the values of a, b, SP, SPP to the text file. The result of SS is not the values of a, b, SP, SPP.

Comment: Then change `rez << SS(a, b, SP, SPP) << endl;` to `SS(a, b, SP, SPP); rez << a << " " << b << " " << SP << " " << SPP << endl;`. Note that you call your function with `SP` as the third parameter and `SPP` as the fourth parameter, but your function has it declared in exactly the opposite order; if this is a typo, fix this as well.

Comment: Y it works now, but i still dont get it why my type not works whatever thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

From a semantic point of view,

```
rez << SS(a, b, SP, SPP) << endl;
```

is equivalent to

```
auto temp = SS(a, b, SP, SPP);
rez << temp << endl;
```

even though the first line won't compile since the return type of `SS` is `void`.

Let's use a function that returns a value that can be used with `rez`.

```
double square(double x)
{
   return x*x;
}
```

You could use:

```
rez << square(0.2) << endl;
```

That is equivalent to:

```
auto temp = square(0.2);
rez << temp << endl;
```

We wouldn't like

```
rez << square(0.2) << endl;
```

to be equivalent to:

```
rez << 0.2 << endl;
```

For that same reason, we wouldn't like

```
rez << SS(a, b, SP, SPP) << endl;
```

to be equivalent to:

```
rez << a << b << SP << SPP << endl;
```

Hope that makes sense.